# Baby Rudin Chapter 1 Exercise 9: Complex Field ordering

Tags: real-analysis

Problem: Suppose $z=a+bi$, $w=c+di$. Define $z<w$ if $a<c$, and also if $a=c$ but $b<d$. Prove that this turns the set of all complex numbers into an ordered set. Does this ordered set has the least-upper-bound property?

In my attempt, I've been using Rudin's definition of an ordered field as a proof structure:

Definition 1.17: An *ordered field* is a *field* $F$ which is also an *ordered set*, such that:

$(1)$ $x+y<x+z$ if $x, y, z \in F$ and $y<z$

$(2)$ $xy>0$ if $x\in F, y \in F, x> 0,$ and $y>0$.

There are some propositions about ordered fields Rudin provides as well which I can prove, but I'm stuck on a part of proving $(2)$.

My attempt on $(2)$: Let $x =a+bi$, $y=c+di$.

Since $0$ = $(0,0)$ or $0 + 0i$, by the problem's defined ordering, $x>0$ if $a > 0$ OR $a = 0$ and $b>0$. And $y>0$ if the same properties hold for $c, d$. $xy = (ac-bd) + (ad+bc)i$. There are four cases to consider if both $x >0$ and $y>0$:

(1) $a >0, c>0$.

What if $ac-bd<0$? $ac > 0$ but if $bd > ac$, then $xy$ is not greater than $0 + 0i$.

(2) $a > 0, c = 0$ but $d > 0$.

$ac = 0, bc = 0$, so $xy = -bd + (ad)i$. If $-bd < 0$, then $xy$ is not greater than $0 + 0i$.

And so forth. Would appreciate any clarification on this.

For the least-upper-bound property, does it suffice to state than for any non-empty subset $E = \{(c, d)\ :\ c, d \in \mathbb{R}\}$ of the set of complex numbers, we observe that all complex numbers are an ordered pair of real numbers and the real field has the least-upper-bound property so we can always find a complex number $(a, b)$, $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a$ and $b$ are supremums of the respective sets $\{c\}$ and $\{d\}$ as defined for subset $E$?

Comment: The ordering on the complex numbers is not a field ordering.

Comment: Consider the subset $A = \{z \in \mathbb C : \text{Re }z < 0\}$. In the ordering defined in the OP, a complex number $w$ is an upper bound for $A$ if and only if $\text{Re }w \geq 0$. Is there a least upper bound?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The terminology Rudin chooses here is confusing: an *ordered field* is not just a field with any order imposed on it (for example, you can put a [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) on the complex numbers).

The content of the definition is that the **order must be compatible in some sense with the field structure, i.e. the field multiplication and addition.**

See problem 8. (p. 22) of chapter 1 of Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis:*

> Prove that no order can be defined on the complex field which turns it into an ordered field. *Hint:* -1 is a square.

The real numbers have a natural total order which is compatible with their field structure. The complex numbers do not; this is because $i^2 = -1$, so we get a contradiction if we assign $i$ to be positive ($i >0$) or negative ($i<0$) -- since we want a *total* order, every number that is not equal to $0$ has to be strictly larger than or strictly smaller than $0$. Again, there is no way to do this which is compatible with the field operations on $\mathbb{C}$.

You will see this elsewhere in mathematics; for example, a topological vector space is not just a vector space which has a topology defined on it; the topology needs to be **compatible** with the vector space operations.

Answer (score 3):

The exercise asks you to show that you get an ordered set. It is not an ordered field; for instance, in the order you gave you have $0<i$, but $i^2=-1<0$, so $(2)$ is not satisfied.